# How to change facial expressions?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, algorithm, actionscript

I need to change photo of a person in different face expressions of that person(smile, sad, ...). Is any body knows the programmatic way or algorithm any information about that please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Although not actionscript specific, I recommend having a look at the [MPT library](http://mplab.ucsd.edu/grants/project1/free-software/MPTWebSite/introduction.html).
Hopefully you could write a wrapper using [Alchemy](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/alchemy/) and use that.

[image: MPT Blink Detection: Eyes Closed]

If it helps, you could download [openframeworks](http://openframeworks.cc) and start prototyping. We had Computer Vision workshop and you could get samples for **blink** and **smile** detection from the [OF Wiki](http://wiki.openframeworks.cc/index.php?title=OF%C2%A0Goldsmiths)

HTH